# NotesDocumentCollection in Mail view

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript

I made new views in my maildatabase and they work fine. A few documents in there show up multiple times, due to the column option to show multiple values as several entries.

So basically, the documents and the view I'm testing with look like this:

- Category A

  - Document A
  - Document A (multiple times due to the option mentioned above)
- Category B

  - Document B

Now I've included a view action, which edits all selected documents in my view. However, when i mark Document A twice AND Document B, db.Unprocesseddocuments.Count only shows 1 document in my collection. When I however select Document A only once and Document B, there's both documents in my collection.

Most of my users unfortunately dont know, that it is the same document they are selecting a 2nd time. Is there any way, to get both documents in my collection even though everything is selected like in the example above?

Thanks in advance!

Edit:
I have noticed, that if I select the same document twice, it doesn't show up in my collection. If I however select it 3 times, it is in my collection again. I think it has to do with layout of maildatabases. Because in other databases, if you select a document once, other entries of the same document are selected too. This is not the case in a maildatabase. So I think in the background it still works like in normal views in other databases, it however is displayed differently. Any solution for that?

Answer (score 1):

My guess is, you select documents in two different ways:

- with a check mark and
- framed

[image]

You get access to selected documents in different ways depending on kind of selection
(like shown in picture).

You get **all** selected documents this way:

```vb
Dim session As New NotesSession
Dim col As NotesDocumentCollection
Dim doc As NotesDocument
Set doc = session.DocumentContext
Set col = session.CurrentDatabase.Unprocesseddocuments
If Not doc Is Nothing Then
    If  Not col.Contains(doc) Then
        Call col.AddDocument(doc)
    End If
End If
Print col.Count
```

Comment: This works only, if the document, that is not added to my collection is currently highlighted. I have also edited my question, maybe this helps.